# existence of non constant analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|>1\}$ and $B=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|\ne 0 \}$.
Then which of the following are correct??
1. There exists a continuous function $f:A\to B$ which is onto.
2.There exists a continuous function $f:B\to A$ which is one-one.
3. There exists a non constant analytic function from B to A.
4. There exists a non constant analytic function from A to B.
Since A and B are homeomorphic 1 and 2 are correct.. But what about 3 and 4 ?

Comment: C is the set of complex numbers

Answer (score 1):

Hints:  For your question #3.  1) consider what $\frac{1}{z}$ does to $A$.  2) Recall what removable singularity is.  For question #4 you probably are missing something as there is clearly a nonconstant function from $A$ to $B$.  Maybe you mean onto?  In which case, think of a function you know really really well (And think of the point 1) above).

Comment: Its non constant analytic function

Comment: Then just think that $A$ is a subset of $B$ and you should be able to get a nonconstant function from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: Why are the first 2 options correct ?  4 is true by open mapping theorem.

Comment: For #1:  $z = re^{it}$, then let $f(z) = (r-1)e^{it}$.  For #2, let $f(z) = (r+1)e^{it}$.  These are in fact homeomorphisms, the second is the inverse of the first.